# MongoDB C# driver 2.0 InsertManyAsync vs BulkWriteAsync

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I have to insert many documents in a MongoDB collection, using the new C# 2.0 driver. Is using either `collection.InsertManyAsync(...)`  or `collection.BulkWriteAsync(...)` making any difference? (particularly about performance).

From what I understand from MongoDB documentation, an insert with an array of documents should be a bulk operation under the hood. Is that correct?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not sure about the answer but this might help: by MongoDB API description  BulkWriteAsync - Performs multiple write operations.
InsertManyAsync - Inserts many documents.

Comment: If all you are doing is "insert" operations then there is effectively no difference. The point of difference is "BulkWrite" effectively allows mixed operations such as "insert", "update" and "remove" in the same batch. Please note that "under the hood", both are using the same Bulk Operations mechanism anyway. So your interpretation is correct.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found the answer looking at the driver source code: the `InsertManyAsync` uses *internally* the `BulkWriteAsync`.

So using `InsertManyAsync` it's the same as writing:

```
List<BsonDocument> documents = ...

collection.BulkWriteAsync(documents.Select(d => new InsertOneModel<BsonDocument>(d)));
```

Obviously, if all operations are Inserts, the `InsertManyAsync` should be used.