# InsertManyAsync vs BulkWriteAsync: in one transaction or not, max rows allowed via MongoDB C# driver

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I have questions on InsertManyAsync vs BulkWriteAsync via the NuGet below:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDB.Driver/2.12.3?_src=template

I want to export 300,000 rows of data around 20 MB, convert them into JSON and import them into Mongo Altas.

My questions:

1 Which operation, `InsertManyAsync` vs `BulkWriteAsync`, is transactional, e.g. all or nothing?

2 What is the maximum rows or size allowed for each operation?

The link below or elsewhere don't have the answers:

[MongoDB C# driver 2.0 InsertManyAsync vs BulkWriteAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32921533/mongodb-c-sharp-driver-2-0-insertmanyasync-vs-bulkwriteasync)

https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.12/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollection_1_BulkWrite.htm

https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.12/apidocs/html/Overload_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollection_1_InsertManyAsync.htm

Answer (score 2):

there is no difference between `InsertManyAsync` and `BulkWriteAsync` other than BulkWriteAsync can work not only with insert. In other words, `InsertManyAsync` calls `BulkWriteAsync` internally.

> Is the operation is one transactional operation, e.g. all or nothing?

see [transactions](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/core/transactions/). Also, see `ordered`/`unordered` option [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/#ordered-vs-unordered-operations).

> What is the maximum rows or size allowed?

I don't think that there is any limitation other then restriction on the document size which is 16 MB. Pay attention that bulk items can be merged into a single document before sending to the server (that should not be bigger 16 MB in sum) or they should be sent separately one by one. This logic depends on whether you use `isOrdered` option and whether all items in your batch are with the same bulk type.

Comment: regarding limits, just noticed this doc https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#mongodb-limit-Write-Command-Batch-Limit-Size, but i didn't use it in practice

Comment: For `InsertMany`: "100,000 writes are allowed in a single batch operation", this makes the data importing more complex than `BulkWriteAsync`. We have 300,000 rows less than 16MB, so it seems bulk import is easier to code. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: if you use the same bulkType for all items in `BulkWriteAsync` you should not see any difference, because `InsertManyAsync` calls `BulkWriteAsync` almost immediately. See this line https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver/MongoCollectionBase.cs#L541

Comment: "100,000 writes are allowed in a single batch operation", which method does that statement apply to?

Comment: Does `InsertManyAsync` and `BulkWriteAsync` has the batch limitation?